# Controlling/Restricting User-specific content in Mongo-Database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm wondering how to control/restrict access from different users to their content stored in mongodb (accessed via mongoose). Let's say there is a data-model to store last wills for users.

My approach would be:

1. Login: authenticate via username and password, store username in session.
2. Middleware: Check Login-Status, query user-model for the stored username and return the user id, attach it to req-object (req.userId)
3. When hitting the route to get actual content (the last-will-model): query the will-model with two conditions: matching willId and matching userId (which is also stored in will-model)

Is this in any way reasonable or even save? Couldn't find any best-practises, all the examples basically end with authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps 1 and 2 can be covered by using [`passport-local`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local), although it's not too hard to implement manually.

Step 3 is reasonable, given that a will belongs to a user and both `willId` and `userId` are required to determine if that user should have access to a particular will document.

Since security is based on session id's, you should obviously use HTTPS and use `httpOnly` and `secure` [session cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#cookie).

Comment: So I guess it's alright to store the documents side by side in the database and only restrict access via the correct query via willId and userId? Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With any of the three ways you can implement authorization, IMO the option I would choose is to use a Middleware.

> It would be a cleaner option, with little impact on the code
>   functionality and easy to maintain for future changes, also separates
>   the concept of authentication and authorization.

I've never used, but have in mind to use [this package](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/connect-roles) in a project that I have to make. You can define your rules and then use it on specific routes.

```
app.get('/', *user.can('access home page'), function (req, res) {
    res.render('private');
});
app.get('/private', *user.can('access private page'), function (req, res) {
    res.render('private');
});
app.get('/admin', *user.can('access admin page'), function (req, res) {
    res.render('admin');
});
```

***Predefined rules**

Comment: Sure, individual middlewares injected in each route is a given. Since it wasn't focus of my question I left this detail out. My question is more about how to store and access user-specific Data securely in a mongo-database.